# Prove that (x - c_j) divides q - q(c_j).

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $c_1, c_2, ..., c_n$ are distinct scalars in field F. Choose one $c_j$ among the c's. 
Let q = $\prod_{i \ne j} (x - c_i)$. I am trying to prove that $(x - c_j)$ | q - q($c_j$). I have done some test cases, and it appears to be true, but I cannot see why.

Comment: $x-a$ divides any polynomial $f$ for which $f(a)=0$.  See that if $f(x)=q(x)-q(c_j)$ then $f(c_j)=0$.

Comment: i see it now, thanks!